# How to draw fat arrow with text inside the arrow in circuits (using circuitikz)?

Tags: arrows, circuitikz, arrowwithtext, electronics

How to draw a fat arrow with the text $R_N$ inside the arrow using Circuitikz? The MWE is given below:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,landscape]{report} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{figure}[H] 
\centering 
\begin{circuitikz} 
\draw (0,0) to [R,l=6$\Omega$] (0,3); 
\draw (0,3) -- (1,3); 
\draw (1,2) -- (1,4); 
\draw (1,4) to [R,l=7$\Omega$] (5,4); 
\draw (1,2) --(2,2); 
\draw (4,2) --(5,2); \draw(5,2) -- (5,4); 
\draw (5,3) to [short] (6,3) node [anchor= west]{A}; 
\draw (0,0) to [short] (6,0) node [anchor=west]{B}; 
\end{circuitikz} 
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

[image: And I want the output like this]
[image: The output is like this...]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone} 
\usepackage[american, siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\begin{document} 
\begin{circuitikz} 
\draw (6,0) node[anchor=west]{B} -- (0,0) to[R,l=6$\Omega$] (0,3) to[short, -*] (1,3); 
\draw (2,2) to[short, *-] (1,2) -- (1,4) to[R,l=7$\Omega$] (5,4) -- (5,2) to[short, -*] (4,2); 
\draw (5,3) to[short, *-] (6,3) node[anchor=west]{A}; 
\node[draw, single arrow, shape border rotate=180, minimum height=1.2 cm, single arrow tip angle=120] at (5.8,1.5) {$R_N$};
\end{circuitikz} 
\end{document}
```

[image: Curcuit diagram with arrow]